ClamAv Java code not working for SSL layer
Below is my ClamAv java code to scan file from from clamAV server.
when secureScan is true then it creates and instance of SSLSocket but while writing the content on server it fails.
Is it release to certificate or handshake issue
@Service
public class ClamAVScanner {
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClamAVScanner.class.getName());
    private int CHUNK_SIZE = 2048;
    private String RESPONSE_OK = "stream: OK";
    private String PONG = "PONG";
    private String FOUND_SUFFIX = "FOUND";
    private String ERROR_SUFFIX = "ERROR";
    private String STREAM_PREFIX = "stream:";

    @Value("${rest.timeout:2000}")
    private int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;

    @Value("${rest.read.timeout:20000}")
    private int READ_TIMEOUT;

    @Value("${rest.clamav.host:localhost}")
    private String HOST;
    @Value("${rest.clamav.port:3310}")
    private int PORT;

    @Value("${rest.clamav.enableFileScan:false}")
    private boolean enableFileScan;

    @Value("${rest.clamav.secureScan:true}")
    private boolean secureScan;

    public VirusScanDto scan(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(enableFileScan)) {
            return new VirusScanDto(VirusScanStatus.PASSED, "File scan is disabled");
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.debug("Start time " + startTime);
        Socket socket = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            if (secureScan)
                socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
            else {
                socket = new Socket();
            }
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT), CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);

            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outStream.write("zINSTREAM\0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            outStream.flush();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            inStream = socket.getInputStream();
            int read = inputStream.read(buffer);

            while (read >= 0) {
                byte[] chunkSize = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(read).array();
                outStream.write(chunkSize);
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);

                if (inStream.available() > 0) {
                    byte[] reply = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
                    throw new IOException(
                            "Reply from server: " + new String(reply, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                }
                read = inputStream.read(buffer);
            }
            outStream.write(new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0});
            outStream.flush();
            LOGGER.debug("Time require to process file " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milli sec");

            return populateVirusScanResult(new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream)).trim());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error connecting to ClamAV, " + e.getMessage());
            return new VirusScanDto(VirusScanStatus.CONNECTION_FAILED, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (Objects.nonNull(inStream)) {
                    inStream.close();
                }
                if (Objects.nonNull(outStream)) {
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                }

                if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error closing instance, " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private VirusScanDto populateVirusScanResult(final String result) {
        VirusScanDto scanResult = new VirusScanDto();
        scanResult.setStatus(VirusScanStatus.FAILED);
        scanResult.setResult(result);

        if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
            scanResult.setStatus(VirusScanStatus.ERROR);
        } else if (RESPONSE_OK.equals(result)) {
            scanResult.setStatus(VirusScanStatus.PASSED);
        } else if (result.endsWith(FOUND_SUFFIX)) {
            scanResult.setSignature(
                    result.substring(STREAM_PREFIX.length(), result.lastIndexOf(FOUND_SUFFIX) - 1).trim());
        } else if (result.endsWith(ERROR_SUFFIX)) {
            scanResult.setStatus(VirusScanStatus.ERROR);
        }
        return scanResult;
    }
}

This code is faling at outStream.flush(); with error -
20-Sep 04:30:41.854 [V5EFDKTJGUMMDSBZXMCPEA] [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR c.m.m.commons.rest.ClamAVScanner - Error connecting to ClamAV, Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message

Any help is appriciated!

Are you running that code on the same host as the clam server?

@g00se No. Clamav is installed on other server on VPN. we can consider it as docker
